# Check if string contain at least two different characters?

Tags: java, regex

I have a given string, and I need to check if this string contain at least two different chatacters/digits/underscores

Valid strings:
"12aab"
"_aaaaaaa"
"bbbc"

Invalid strings:
"a"
"**______**"
"333333333333"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a homework/assignment question!

Comment: Possibly is homework but it's quite an interesting problem to look at during a recompilation!

Comment: @user1422513 People actually put some effort to help you with your homework, put some effort back and accept an answer. People want their points

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex to match the strings, which have two different letter or numbers or `_` symbols,

```
^\w*?(\w)(?!\1|$)\w*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vY0gH6/3)

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    System.out.println(isMatch("12aab", "^\\w*?(\\w)(?!\\1|$)\\w*$"));
    System.out.println(isMatch("_aaaaaaa", "^\\w*?(\\w)(?!\\1|$)\\w*$"));
    System.out.println(isMatch("bbbc", "^\\w*?(\\w)(?!\\1|$)\\w*$"));
    System.out.println(isMatch("3333", "^\\w*?(\\w)(?!\\1|$)\\w*$"));
    System.out.println(isMatch("a", "^\\w*?(\\w)(?!\\1|$)\\w*$"));
    System.out.println(isMatch("________", "^\\w*?(\\w)(?!\\1|$)\\w*$"));
}
private static boolean isMatch(String s, String pattern) {
    try {
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(s);
        return matcher.matches();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return false;
    }  
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
false
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to use a regex if the positions are very different.

Just use a Set of `Character` and if the size of set is 2,you are sure

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  public boolean valid(String s){ // valid if contains 2 different chars or more
    if(s == null || s.length() < 2 )
        return false;
    char c = s.charAt(0);
    int i = 1;
    int size = s.length();
    while(i < size && c == s.charAt(i))
        i ++;
    return i != size;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try a lookahead to the next letter/digit/underscore, then ensure it is not the original:

```
(\w).*(?=\w)(?!\1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method with a simple for loop that checks if the `Strings` you pass are valid.

```
boolean isValid(String s){
    char a = s.charAt(0); //store the first char of the String
    for(int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++)
        if(s.charAt(i) != a) //compare against every other char
            return true; // if at least one match, String is valid
    return false; // String consists of the same character.

}
```

Testing the method with:

```
System.out.println(isValid("12aab"));
System.out.println(isValid("_aaaaaaa"));
System.out.println(isValid("bbbc"));
System.out.println(isValid("a"));
System.out.println(isValid("______"));
System.out.println(isValid("333333333333"));
```

will output:

```
true
true
true
false
false
false
```

Hope this helps